# svg logos not working properly in bootstrap in firefox and edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have made this little website for myself: http://jonathanpabst.dk/website/HTML/index.html and it works fine on google chrome.

But when i enter the site on microsoft edge or firefox my svg logos under the section "mine Kompetencer" is not in a row like it would be in chrome and they become big and ruin the page.

i have been unsuccessful in figuring out what is wrong myself, and hope someone in here might have the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want help, please create a [mcve]. I.e. put your faulty code in this question.  An offsite URL is not useful, because when you fix it, this question will become virtually useless.

Answer (score 0):

Just give them a max-width of 95px and it will work.